# How to implement a ordered many2many relation in the Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms, many-to-many

Here a sample models I have:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models,CharField(max_lenght=128)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True,
                                      related_name='item_category',
                                      null=True, through='ItemCategory')


class ItemCategory(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

My problem is how do I arrange the order in the admin side? In other words, I need to expand the widget functionality to allow the user to change the order of the selected items and when the form is saved, the selected items will save the item order in ItemCategory.order. I have the form that looks like this:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    _items = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        label='Items',
        queryset=Items.objects.all(),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(verbose_name="Items",
                                      is_stacked=False)
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FamilyAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Meta class:

```
class Category(models.Model): 
     # ...
     class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: That does not meet my requirements that the user can manipulate the order of the items in a category.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question properly. Have you checked out this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2306/)?